# why angular httpClient is reactive?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm a little confused about reactive programming with angular httpClient.
what's the point of being reactive here?

as I know the reactive style is useful when we have a continues data flow, is it possible that we could have something like this in angular httpClient?
for example, send one request to the server and get multiple responses continuously from the server.
Also, I found that observable doesn't complete when it gets a response from the server so I think it waits for other data.

Is it create a new observable for each request? if yes, is it necessary to unsubscribe from them later?

Comment: You are asking four different questions here. Can you clarify your a question for a single focus?

Comment: Yes but I think they are related to each other.

Comment: The simple answer to "why angular httpClient is reactive?" is that http requests are asynchronous and can benefit from the utilities RxJS provides. Depending on how you are going to use that data returned from the httpClient, an observable can be very helpful in providing the asynchronous response to the subscriber in a programmatic way.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754 http request are async., most of them will emit 1 value and then complete. Yes, new observables are created for every request, and no, you dont need to unsubscribe from them.

Comment: I don't understand why you got downvotes. l had the same questionings

Comment: @danbord I was asking myself exactly the same question.

Answer (score 1):

One example I came across that uses multiple values is **progress events**
Ref [Angular httpClient Progress Events](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events)

```js
http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
  // Via this API, you get access to the raw event stream.
  // Look for upload progress events.
  if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
    // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
    const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    console.log(`File is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`);
  } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
  }
});
```